# What is BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY?

Tags: input, header-file

I'm writing kinda virtual keyboard using uinput and during looking into what all should I put into

```
ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, ???);
```

I found `input-event-codes.h`. Some constants there are pretty self-explanatory (`KEY_1`, `KEY_D`, ...), but some are a bit more cryptic.

Is there anywhere documentation where those keycodes are listed and explained? I tried google, but `BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY` didn't lead me to anywhere useful :/ What is this keycode useful for?

PS: If there is complete list somewhere, that would be nice, there is a few more quite interesting (`KEY_HIRAGANA`? `KEY_102ND`? ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation/input), quite a lot of it too.

Happy is close to joy, and this association is supported by the following search result:

[image]

I wouldn't expect every event to have a strict definition. But there's a note in `input-event-codes.h` stating:

> /*  * Keys and buttons  *  * Most of the keys/buttons are modeled
>   after USB HUT 1.12  * (see http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage).  *
>   Abbreviations in the comments:  * AC - Application Control  * AL -
>   Application Launch Button  * SC - System Control  */

Answer (score 5):

Specifically for BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY, here is the [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/cf2f765f1896064e34c6f0f2ef896ff058dd5c06) where that range was added. These events appear to just be generic joystick events for devices with more than 16 buttons.

As for the name, I found [this discussion](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg06419.html) on naming the events. Your guess is as good as mine on why this name was picked. It appears to be a fun name out of frustration with the previous "BTN_TRIGGER" range being too small.

Answer (score 0):

BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY is a signal in the LIRC name space. I think your're trying to setup a IR / Radio device or mouse / joystick ?